# When did the distinction between the spoken and written English grammars became recognized?

Tags: language-evolution

It is generally accepted today that the grammars and vocabularies of the spoken and the written English differ in important ways. Is it known when this distinction between the English grammars become recognized - for example, mentioned in a book or an article?

Comment: spoken language always has more colloquialisms, some of which eventually make their way into written language. That's one way how language evolves.

Comment: @msam I understand that the distinction has been there for roughly as long as the written language exists. However, my question is not when the split *happened*, but when it became *recognized* by scientists who study language grammars (specifically, English grammars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Researchers became aware of the differences, or least seriously wrote about them, only with the development of technology to record speech. Before that, the written language was paramount. For some it still, mistakenly, is.